# React-native-reanimated: how to assign Value to ScrollView scrollEnabled property?

Tags: react-native, react-native-reanimated

I'm trying to control ScrollView using reanimated `Value`. Works fine on iOS, but android throws this error:

```
java.lang.double cannot be cast to java.lang.boolean
```

Here is the code:

```
import React, { PureComponent } from 'react'
import { StyleSheet, Text, ScrollView} from 'react-native'
import Animated, {event, set} from 'react-native-reanimated'
import {
  PanGestureHandler,
  NativeViewGestureHandler,
} from 'react-native-gesture-handler'

class ComponentName extends PureComponent {
  scrollEnabled = new Value(0)
  panRef = React.createRef<PanGestureHandler>()
  listRef = React.createRef<ScrollView>()

  onGestureEvent = event(
    // some event with conditions...
    set(this.scrollEnabled, 1)
    // ... 
  )
  
  render () {
    return (
      <PanGestureHandler
        onGestureEvent={this.onGestureEvent}
        ref={this.panRef}
        simultaneousHandlers={this.listRef}
      >
        <Animated.ScrollView
          scrollEnabled={this.scrollEnabled}
          simultaneousHandlers={this.panRef}
        >
          <Text>ComponentName</Text>
          <Text>ComponentName</Text>
          <Text>ComponentName</Text>
          <Text>ComponentName</Text>
          ...
        </Animated.ScrollView>
      </PanGestureHandler>
    )
  }
}
```

How do I make it work?

[image]

Comment: Did you try to change "set(this.scrollEnabled, 1)" to "set(this.scrollEnabled, true)"?

Comment: yes, same outcome

Comment: What about giving the animated scrollview ref and changing it this way?

Comment: neither scrollEnabled nor setNativeProps is available on the ref

Comment: ran out of ideas. sorry. good louck.

Comment: One last one: when you set ""set(this.scrollEnabled, true)" did you changed the initial state to be "scrollEnabled = false" instead of "scrollEnabled = new Value(0)"?

Comment: no, I was changing it to new Value(true). I'll try this, thanks!